# How to divide SQL/MySQL query output into multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a following query:

```
SELECT  COUNT (*) AS Total, Program, Status
FROM APP_PGM_CHOICE
WHERE Program IN ( 'EX', 'IM')
AND  APP_PGM_REQ_DT  >= '20150101'
AND APP_PGM_REQ_DT  <= '20150131'
AND Status IN ( 'PE','DN','AP')
GROUP BY  Program, Status
ORDER BY  Program, Status
```

And the output is:

```
Total   Program   Status
12246   "EX"      "AP"
13963   "EX"      "DN"
21317   "EX"      "PE"
540     "IM"      "AP"
2110    "IM"      "DN"
7184    "IM"      "PE"
```

And I want the output like:

```
Total1  Program1   Total2   Program2  Status
12246     EX        540       IM        AP
13963     EX        2110      IM        DN
21317     EX        7184      IM        PE
```

Can I do ii? If yes whats the way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you could do it this way:

```
Select T1.Total Total1, T1.Program Program1, T2.Total Total2, T2.Program Program2, T1.Status

From
(SELECT  COUNT (*) AS Total, Program, Status
FROM APP_PGM_CHOICE
WHERE Program = 'EX'
AND  APP_PGM_REQ_DT  >= '20150101'
AND APP_PGM_REQ_DT  <= '20150131'
AND Status IN ( 'PE','DN','AP')
GROUP BY  Program, Status
ORDER BY  Program, Status) T1

INNER JOIN

(SELECT  COUNT (*) AS Total, Program, Status
FROM APP_PGM_CHOICE
WHERE Program = 'IM'
AND  APP_PGM_REQ_DT  >= '20150101'
AND APP_PGM_REQ_DT  <= '20150131'
AND Status IN ( 'PE','DN','AP')
GROUP BY  Program, Status
ORDER BY  Program, Status) T2 on T1.Status = T2.Status
```

Comment: No problem at all, happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a UNION query and some simple selects

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(total1) as total1, GROUP_CONCAT(proram1) as program1, GROUP_CONCAT(total2) as total2, GROUP_CONCAT(program2) as program2
FROM 
(SELECT total AS total1, program AS program1, null AS total2, null AS program2
WHERE program = 'EX'
UNION
SELECT null AS total1, null AS program1, total AS total2, program AS program2
WHERE program = 'IM') t
```

This is the easy way to pivot rows into columns

Answer (score 0):

In sql Temp Table is Very Usefull and Easy Funda..

Easy Way to Get Output.

select Total,Prog,Status 
Into #TempAA
from CGT
Where Prog='EX' 
Group by Status,Total,Prog

select Total,Prog,Status 
Into #TempBB
from CGT
Where Prog='IM' 
Group by Status,Total,Prog

select A.Total as [Total1],A.Prog as [Program1],B.Total as [Total2],B.Prog as [Program2],A.Status 
from #TempAA A
Inner join #TempBB B On b.Status =A.status